# MSSQL server not working with php-Error shown

Tags: php, sql-server, sqlsrv

I am currently using `PHP 5.2`, with `Microsoft Server 2008 R2`, and using sqlsrv, with SQL native client 10.0.

I have changed the php extension to include `extension=php_sqlsrv_52_ts_vc6.dll` and have done the necessary changes to `php.ini`.

The `php.info` page also shows the sqlsrv has been installed successfully, but I am not sure why when I try to use sqlsrv command, it is unable to connect to SQL server.  This is my codes.

```
    <?php

    $myServer = "MYSERVER\SQLEXPRESS";
    $myUser = "sa";
    $myDB = "Form"; 


   $conInfo = array('Database'=>$myDB, 'UID'=>$myUser);
   $conn = sqlsrv_connect( $myServer, $conInfo);

   if( $conn ) {
     echo "Connection established.<br />";
   }else{
     echo "Connection could not be established.<br />";
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
   }
    ?>
```

It shows [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'sa'. [message]. Could someone be kind enough to tell me what seems to go wrong?

I need the answer urgently.Thank you.

Comment: Watch you server error_log. It may contain useful information. You can also check if error_reporting is enabled in php.ini, in case it's disabled,,  turn it to ON. It will help you during development stage.

Comment: I'm sorry, I think I did not state more, I'm using IIS server. :(

Comment: Sorry, I removed the apache part but you may have an error log somewhere I think !

Comment: Can you tell me where can I find the error log? I only know that I have enabled my Server Reporting Server in my SQL server configuration, but still nothing comes out. I think the sqlsrv command is not recognized, but I don't know why since phpinfo shows that it is installed successfully.

Comment: Sorry I don't know IIS :(

Comment: Awww it's alright, thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Try with this -     
<?php
$myServer = "MYSERVER\SQLEXPRESS";
$myUser = "sa";
$myDB = "Form"; 

$conInfo = array('Database'=>$myDB, 'UID'=>$myUser,  'PWD'=>'');
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $myServer, $conInfo);

if( $conn ) {
     echo "Connection established.<br />";
}else{
     echo "Connection could not be established.<br />";
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
?>
```

Comment: $conInfo = array('Database'=>$myDB, 'UID'=>$myUser. 'PWD'=>'');

Put your password if you have otherwise send it as blank.